# Counting characters in text file

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that reads from a file and counts how many lowercase letters, uppercase letters, whitespace characters (tab, enter etc.) and everything else.

This is the code I have and it shows the right amount of letters but for some reason the "other" counter show way more then it should. Anyone know what I have done wrong?

```
    File file = new File("C:\\Temp\\Test.txt");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("");

    for (int i = 0; i < file.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.next().charAt(0);

        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                isLower++;
            } else {
                isUpper++;
            }
        } else if (Character.isSpaceChar(c) || (c == '\n') || (c == '\t')) {
            isSpace++;
        } else {
            isOther++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: For your second conditional, note that there is a `Character.isWhitespace` function that will cover all three of those cases.

Comment: Are you counting digits?

Comment: Aside from your problem, your variable names suggest that `isLower, isUpper, isSpace, isOther` are booleans. You should consider renaming them.

Answer (score 0):

isOther counter contain \r an other stuff as utf8 characters multiply 2. Check encoding and check file format.